Finite product topology and some properties
I need help with two items. First, I would like you to check if the proof I wrote for the following statement is correct:
Let $\lbrace X_j \rbrace _{j=1}^n$ be a finite collection of topological spaces. Let's consider $X=X_1\times\dots\times X_n$ with the product topology.

If $X$ is Hausdorff, then $X_j$ is Hausdorff for all $j$.

My proof: We can simplify by admitting that $X=X_1\times X_2$. Then, fix $i\in\lbrace 1, 2\rbrace$. Given $p,q\in X_i$ with $p\neq q$, and given $x\in X_j$ with $j\neq i$, let's consider $(p,x), (q,x)\in X$. Since $X$ is Hausdorff, there exist open sets $U, V\subset X$ such that $(p,x)\in U$, $(q,x)\in V$, and $U\cap V = \emptyset$. Since $U, V$ are open in $X$, there necessarily exist open sets $U_i, V_i\subset X_i$ and open sets $U_j, V_j\subset X_j$ such that $U=U_i\times U_j$ and $V=V_i\times V_j$ (this is correct, right?)
Moreover, we have that $U\cap V = (U_i\times U_j)\cap(V_i\times V_j)=\emptyset$, where $U_i\times U_j\neq\emptyset$ and $V_i\times V_j\neq\emptyset$.
Thus, we need to show that $U_i\cap V_i = \emptyset$. Indeed, if there exists $y\in U_i\cap V_i$, then for $U_i\times U_j\neq\emptyset$ and $V_i\times V_j\neq\emptyset$, there must necessarily exist $z\in U_j\cap V_j$, and then we would have $(y,z)\in (U_i\cap V_i)\times (U_j\cap V_j) = (U_i\times U_j)\cap(V_i\times V_j)\neq\emptyset$, which is a contradiction. Therefore, $U_i\cap V_i = \emptyset$ and $X_i$ is Hausdorff. $\blacksquare$
Is this correct? To me, it seems so.
Below is the next item:

If $X$ is regular, then every $X_j$ is regular.

My intuition tells me that this proof is analogous to the previous one, but I have the following question: does any closed set $C \in X$ necessarily imply the existence of closed sets $C_i\subset X_i$ and $C_j\subset X_j$ such that $C=C_i\times C_j$?
If so, it seems to me that the proof of this statement will be identical to the other.
Are my arguments correct?
Thank you.

You set $p,q\in X_i$ and $x\in X_j$, but then you write $(p,x)$ which means that $i=1$  and $j=2$, so your notation is innecesarily complex.

Both questions have a positive answer, simply by noting that each $X_j$ embeds into $X$ as a subspace, and any subspace of a Hausdorff/regular space is Hausdorff/regular.

Also, the claim that if $U \subset X_1 \times X_2$ is open, then $U = U_1 \times U_2$ is false. (If both $X_i$ all discrete, then $X_1 \times X_2$ is discrete, but certainly not all subsets of $X_1 \times X_2$ can be decomposed as products.) The similar statement for closed sets is also false for the same reason.

You have to assume that all the $X_j$ are non-empty.
